# Overpass Turbo query for all ocean entities

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I'm looking for an overpass turbo query that gives me all (salt) water entities.
Currently, this is my query (using the [overpass web interface](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1EpC)):

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
(
  node["place"="sea"]({{bbox}});
  way["place"="sea"]({{bbox}});
  relation["place"="sea"]({{bbox}});
 
  node["natural"="bay"]({{bbox}});
  way["natural"="bay"]({{bbox}});
  relation["natural"="bay"]({{bbox}});

  node["water"]({{bbox}});
  way["water"]({{bbox}});
  relation["water"]({{bbox}});
  
  node["natural"="ocean"]({{bbox}});
  way["natural"="ocean"]({{bbox}});
  relation["natural"="ocean"]({{bbox}});
);

out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Basically, this works fine. But for certain sea elements, I do not get any results.
Is this because some are just not mapped and sea is considered as a base layer?

Take this point for example: https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=19/36.00849/-5.44347

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange! What is your desired output? Do you want polygons of all salt water surfaces (then you would not need the nodes of course)? Or nodes with the names of (salt) water entities (no ways and relations needed)? I think that more details are necessary to answer your question. Please have in mind that the oceans/larger seas do not exist as relations in OSM but are rendered based on `natural=coastline` rings (clockwise and without any gaps). By the way, you can query nodes, ways and relations together using e.g. `nwr[natural=bay]({{bbox}});`.

Comment: Are these prepared datasets maybe useful for you? https://osmdata.openstreetmap.de/data/coastlines.html or https://osmdata.openstreetmap.de/data/water-polygons.html

Comment: @winnewoerp Thank you. 
I'd like to have the polygons of the sea. In the same way as I get them by querying `nwr[natural=bay]({{bbox}});` But it is like I already assumed: "_larger seas do not exist as relations_". So have to find a way using the coastlines. 
I guess my question is answered, at least for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@winnewoerp](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/52808/winnewoerp) stated: "*the oceans/larger seas do not exist as relations in OSM but are rendered based on natural=coastline rings*", you have to make use of the coastline

```
nwr["natural"="coastline"]({{bbox}});
```

or use the prepared land or water polygon data sets here: https://osmdata.openstreetmap.de/data/. These are split into 1° Lat/Lon tiles, which comes very handy.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on code which joins coastline segments, repairs gaps and completes polygons for a chosen area. This is for an app I am working on. I am happy to post the relevant code when it’s ready.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Isn't that addressed here? [https://github.com/osmcode/osmcoastline](https://github.com/osmcode/osmcoastline)